# Msg 537, Level 16, State 2, Line 16 Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table `area` with a column `AreaID` of type `varchar` in SQL Server. The values are like this

```
1.1, 1.1.1, 1.1.2, 2.1, 2.1.1, 2.1.2
```

and so on. It is hierarchy value has parent and children.

I have a stored procedure to check maximum value when I got the maximum value in database it is so the value + 1

This stored procedure works while I input parent =  1.3, but when I input = 1.3.18.5 it is getting error

This is my stored procedure

```
DECLARE @Parent VARCHAR(20)
DECLARE @ID VARCHAR(20)
SET @Parent = '1.3.18.5'

SET @ID = NULL

SELECT TOP 1
        @ID = AreaID
FROM    dbo.Area
WHERE   ParentID = @Parent
ORDER BY CAST(SUBSTRING(AreaID, LEN(@Parent) + 2,
                        LEN(AreaID) - LEN(@Parent) - 1) AS INT) DESC

IF ( @ID IS NULL ) 
    BEGIN
        SET @ID = @Parent + '.' + CAST(1 AS VARCHAR(50))
    END
ELSE 
    BEGIN
        SET @ID = @Parent + '.'
            + CAST(CAST(SUBSTRING(@ID, LEN(@Parent) + 2,
                                  LEN(@ID) - LEN(@PARENT) - 1) AS INT) + 1 AS VARCHAR(50)) 
    END

SELECT  @ID
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it should error out since in this case the specified index is out of range. To point out, your `AreaID` having value `2.1.2` but your `@Parent = '1.3.18.5'`. So in the below statement, you are essentially saying, start taking substring from `AreaID` at starting position 10 which doesn't exists since `AreaId` value maximum length is 5. So, the error.

```
SUBSTRING(AreaID, LEN(@Parent) + 2,
```

Moreover, error message itself is self explanatory and it's clearly saying that you have specified an invalid length parameter to the `SUBSTRING` function.